# Saturation Bug with the backdrop-filter in a mega menu

Tags: css, filter

I have a problem with the backdrop-filter...
Here are two images on how it is supposed to look and the bug:
[This is an image of the bug.][1]
[This is an image of how it is supposed to look.][2]

And here is the CSS, which is not working right:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
```

Here is the link: https://arvaloo.com/contact/ and https://arvaloo.com/imprint/

Looking forward to any help!

Thank you in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV6Qs.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgAIZ.jpg

Comment: One image has the background the other doesn't... what should we be looking at?

Comment: Hello Terry, this is exactly the same header and menu. I cannot understand wie on the one the backdrop-filter is working, and on the other it is not.

Comment: Not sure how the backdrop filter works when there is no background image at all. Share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example in the question itself.